# Running Openzepplin from docker

Tags: solidity, docker, openzeppelin-contracts

I am trying to build a docker image using open zepplin libraries. It works until it has to import the zepellin library, for which it can't seem to find.

Here is what my docker image looks like :

```
FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE 64

COPY cdp-contracts/ ./rpc
COPY cdp-platform/  ./backend

RUN rm -rf backend/node_modules
RUN rm -rf rpc/node_modules

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    g++ \
    libpng-dev \
    libtool \
    make \
    nasm \
    python \
    git \
  && npm i -g wait-on concurrently truffle npm@latest \
  && concurrently 'cd rpc;  npm init -y ; npm install --save-exact openzeppelin-solidity; npm init -y ; npm i npm@latest -g ' 'cd backend; npm i npm@latest -g ; npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source' \
  && apk del .gyp

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/rpc

RUN truffle compile --all

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/backend

RUN mkdir -p build/
RUN ln -sf ../../rpc/build/contracts build/contracts

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/backend

EXPOSE 3001

CMD [ "npm", "run", "middleware" ]
```

Here is the import line from my contract :

```
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
```

> Note: From the documentation:
>
> After that, you'll get all the library's contracts in the
>   node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts folder. Because Truffle
>   and other Ethereum development toolkits understand node_modules, you
>   can use the contracts in the library like so
>
> ```
> import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol';
>
> contract MyContract is Ownable {
>   ...
> }
> ```

Reference: https://openzeppelin.org/api/docs/get-started.html

When I try to reference the node module, or call it import it as above, I keep running into this error:

> Error: Could not find
>   /usr/src/app/rpc/node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol
>   from any sources; imported from
>   /usr/src/app/rpc/contracts/CarbonToken.sol
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-resolver/index.js:76:1

I will appreciate any guidance on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a packagelock.json file there messing it up. Once I took it out it worked like a treat